# How to search a file in eclipse clearcase?

Tags: clearcase-remote-client

I am using eclipse clearcase remote client. Everytime i wish to check out the file, i am going into the long branch.
Is there any way to find a file directly in the root like searching?

Comment: Are you using a view with a configspec?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CCRC, you are using a snapshot view, which have an config spec specifying:

- what you are selecting (this is the part you need to adjust to check out the right version in the right branch)
- what you are loading on your disk.

As mentioned in this [comparison matrix between CCRC and other ClearCase instances](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21233090),

> CCRC can only search the local copy area’s database for checkouts, hijacks, view privates.

I would recommend making a *second* CCRC web view, and make some tests on that view (with a small set of files loaded).